# Google Sheets: Using REGEX to include markdown hypertext

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet with 20+ users adding info. The sheet contains a column for "URL" but the URL with the word "visit/" must be in [hypertext markdown](https://anvilproject.org/guides/content/creating-links) in order for the links to be clickable on the internal dashboard. Thanks in advance!

My attempt but will not work if there is more than 1 link:

```
=if(REGEXMATCH(A2,"visit/"),CONCATENATE("[",A2,"](http://",A2,")"))
```

[Example GSheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MdVHcczreOTy5sT0fz9tpGENq0qaI7dEph63MCh8yGI/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,join(", ",map(index(trim(split(Σ,", "&char(10)))),lambda(Λ,regexreplace(Λ,"^visit/.*","[$0](http://$0)")))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks. By any chance can you share with me any Excel Resouces (websites/videos) do you use to learn how to create complicated formulas? Or is it all through experience?

Comment: [these explanatory videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLv9Pf9aNgemvXxLZfObnb3cvcG6gerfOB) on the new functions usage should be helpful